# Merge a list and an array of JSON in JenkinsFile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a list that looks like this -
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

I have an array of JSON objects that looks like this -

Full List: [{
"Key": "CI",
"Value": "SERVICES"
}
, {
"Key": "CI",
"Value": ""
}]

Expected output -

Full List: [{
"Key": "CI",
"Value": "SERVICES",
"Account": "1"
}
, {
"Key": "CI",
"Value": "",
"Account": "2"
}]

How to do this inside jenkins file using groovy. I have tried and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
def list = [1,2,3]
def full_list = ['{ "Key": "CI", "Value": "SERVICES" }' , '{ "Key": "CI", "Value": "" }']
full_list.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(item)
    json["Account"] = list[index]
    full_list[index] = json
}
```

Output:

> ["[Account:1, Key:CI, Value:SERVICES]", "[Account:2, Key:CI, Value:]"]

https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zddfxgan

We simply loop through the array, convert each item to a json map object, append the new "Account" key into the map with the corresponding value of the other list, and replace the original array item with the modified map value.

Comment: Thank you @M B, it worked just fine. I was trying out the same thing that you mentioned but probably was unaware that there is a JSONSlurper for parsing JSON in groovy.